# Will this USB wall wort/adaptor work in Cuba? [Photos]

Tags: power

[image: USB Wall Adaptor]

The Label says

> TYPE:HX9200
>   INPUT: 100 - 240V ~ 50/60Hz,3.5W
>   OUTPUT: 5V [DC Output Symbol] 2.5W

And the rest is symbols and such.

Guardalavaca specifically.

Answer (score 1):

That's the European plug, yes?

It would appear to be dual voltage, which would mean you could plug it into either the 110 or 220 V sockets in Cuba (they do vary).  Most 220V sockets could take the European rounded two prong plug like that, as well as the flatter 2 prong US plug (still fits).

However, as a suggestion - you could consider getting a universal adaptor anyway just in case, with surge protection and ideally multi-plug - some come with multiple USB ports and plugs, which would cover you not only for any surprises there, but for travel to many other countries in the future as well.

Comment: I don't know if it's European, I'm assuming so, but I received it wrongly with a product I own, but it looks very much so.